# compositing problem

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am new to the compositor.I was trying to composite an image.But the image was not fully in there.

this is my render.[image: my image]

and I want to mix it with this
[image: I want to mix it with this]

After I composite it,the image was not fully in there
[image]

Comment: Use alpha over, not add.

Comment: it still the same

Comment: Ah your image is clipped and that is what you mean. Change your rendering dimension percentages and sizes to match the background plate.